# Meaning of rails expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in Ruby on rails. I am following a book "Agile web development with rails"

In the book they showed how to set up session by the following code segment

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
private
  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end
end
```

What I don't understand is that they set it in private section but still I can access this function from other class and also I don't understand what this mean by :cart_id I mean how they get value in the :cart_it variable although in the application I never set value in that variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `current_cart` is set to private, but it's defined in the `ApplicationController`. All the other controllers are likely to inherit from that controller so they have access to it.

`:cart_id` is a symbol. The way you set/get session variables in Rails is

```
# set
session[:key] = value

# get 
session[:key]
```

You are setting the value exactly three line below, in the rescue block.

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
end
```

The flow is the following: when the cart does not exist, you create it an store the id in the session. When the cart exists, you return it.

You may need to study some Ruby before going ahead with your Rails development, or even the simplest code fragments will be totally unknown to you.